# Detect Mousedown Event in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know how to detect mousedown event on a directive that is clicked. However my directive also needs to become unforcused or deselected when mouse is down outside of my directive/ element. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a link function in the directive which binds a mousedown event handler on the document. Then, bind another mousedown event on the directive element itself. The latter handler should also call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling all of the way up to the document level:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
  angular.element(document).bind('mousedown', function(){
    console.log('clicked on document');
  });

  elem.bind('mousedown', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('clicked on directive');
  });
}
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5U8mr8gBTQJajLzb3wSj?p=preview)

Comment: will this automatically $apply() as well?